# Как сделать фоновый отсчет времени на Python

Tags: python, время

Допустим у меня есть программа там например вопросы на которые нужно отвечать. И пока я отвечаю на них уходит отсчет времени например 10 секунд. Если 10 секунд прошли и я еще не успел ответить на все вопросы то появляется надпись "вы проиграли" а если я ответил на все вопросы то таймер просто скидываеться

Comment: Здесь нужно, вероятно, применять многопоточность.

Comment: Такое лучше делать на JS, ну или на PyQt или ещё каком-то фреймворке с нормальным GUI, а не просто на питоне.

Answer (score 3):

Можно установить таймер:

```
import threading

def timer_expired():
    print("Время истекло! Вы проиграли.")

timer = threading.Timer(10.0, timer_expired)
timer.start()

# Ваш код с вопросами и ответами
input("Земля плоская? ")
# Если успели ответить на все вопросы, то останавливаем таймер:
timer.cancel()
```